# std::list - как перемещаться по списку?

Tags: c++, list, stl

Извините, подскажите, а как перемещаться по элементам std:list ?

Перемещение используя итератор, как в std::vector или std::deque - поему то не работает.

```
std::vector<int>my_vector;

std::vector<int>::iterator my_vec_iter = my_vector.end() - 1;  //Все нормально



std::list<int> my_list;

std::list<int>::iterator my_list_iter = my_list.end() - 1;   //Ошибка
```

Comment: `std::list` поддерживает только оператор ++ и --

Comment: я имел ввиду итератор не поддерживает + и - , так как он с последовательним доступом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector` — контейнер с *произвольным* доступом, а `list` — только с *последовательным*.

```
std::list<int> my_list;
std::list<int>::iterator my_list_iter = my_list.end();
--my_list_iter;
```

А с `forward_list` не получится даже этого...

Answer (score 6):

Если очень хочется написать именно `my_list.end() - 1;`, то нужно просто использовать правильные функции - `std::prev(my_list.end())`. Эта функция перегружена правильно для разных контейнеров и может возвратить правильный итератор. Для `forward_list` оно не работает, но это и контейнер такой интересный, очень и очень урезанный.

Comment: Не только  для forward_list. Для любого однонаправленного не должно

Comment: В теории, никто не мешает написать такую перегрузку. Вот только скорость работы будет не очень:)

Answer (score 4):

Используйте инкременты:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {

    std::list<int> list;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        list.push_back(i);
    }

    std::list<int>::iterator it = list.end();
    while (it != list.begin()) {
        --it;
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror list_it.cpp
>
> $ ./a.out
> 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
> ```